# Extra slide in between itemize environment

Tags: beamer

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\mode<presentation>

\title[AAA]{AAA}
%\subtitle
\institute[AAA]{BBB}
\author{AAA}
\date{BBB}

% Define the title of each inserted pre-subsection frame
\newcommand*\titleSubsec{Next Subsection}
% Define the title of the "Table of Contents" frame
\newcommand*\titleTOC{Outline}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Section 1 - A}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> Blablabla:
            \begin{itemize}
              \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
            \end{itemize}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \item <2-> Blablabla:
            \begin{itemize}
              \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Section 1 - B}
    PHOTO
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Section 1 - A}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> Blablabla:
            \begin{itemize}
              \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
            \end{itemize}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \item <2-> Blablabla:
            \begin{itemize}
              \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item Blablabla
                \item $\cdots\cdots\cdots$
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I basically want is to get rid of page 2 and page 4 of the pdf output file. That is, on the first slide I want to show item <1>, then I want to show a slide with just a photo, and then I want to show item <1> together with item <2> on a new slide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this task, you need two things:

- if you wand to display only a specific overlay of a frame, you can use `\begin{frame}<1> ... \end{frame}`
- to reuse an "old" frame, `\againframe<>{}` is the answer

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=frame1]
    \frametitle{Section 1 - A}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> Blablabla 1:
        \item <2-> Blablabla 2:
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Section 1 - B}
    PHOTO
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{frame1}

\end{document}
```

[image]